# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following method that checks if I have object in the first index and add to it if empty

```
private void GetRestriction(TableRow[] RistrictionsArgs)
{
    var restrictionList = new List<Restriction>();
    foreach (var restriction in RistrictionsArgs)
    {

        var Id = int.Parse(restriction.Values.ElementAt(1));
        var test = restrictionList[Id - 1];
        if (test == null)
        {
            restrictionList[Id - 1] = new Restriction()
            {
                SequenceID = Id.ToString(),

            };
            test = restrictionList[Id - 1];

        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is when it reaches the line `var test = restriction[Id-1];` it throws  *'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'*
What am I missing? how can check the first element is empty and then add element to it?

Comment: Please don't have multiple variables with the same name.

Comment: And it would be good to compile your code befor posting.

Comment: @Jashaszun I update it in the new post

Comment: `if (restrictionList.Length < (Id - 1)) { continue; }` adding this before `var test...` will verify that the array has that index.

Comment: @HXD And I think you have enough experience here to know how to format a question.

Comment: There is no element in `restrictionList`. you are just instantiating it but not adding anything to it.

Answer (score 1):

No items exist in `restrictionList` (the length is 0), so trivially `restrictionList[anyIndex]` is invalid and will throw the reported exception. Lists do *not* automatically grow on an index operation.

To check if the the collection is empty, use `restrictionList.Length == 0` (or other check as appropriate to see if a particular Id is in range). Then use `Add` to add a new element - not another index which will also throw an exception for the same reason as above.

Showing the actual ID's and explaining the algorithm and expected result will likely lead to better answers, as the above notes say what is currently wrong, and not necessarily "how write it correctly".